# How to get last inserted RawContacts ID after newInsert into address book programactically?

Tags: android, contactscontract, rawcontacts

I succeeded in inserting contacts into the address book and I need to save a reference of the contact in my app. I figured that the best way to save the reference is to get the RawContacts ID itself.

Is there a way for me to directly get the ID back from the address book right after the insertion of the the new contact? Or do I have to get every records out and compare them with my data to get the RawContacts ID?

I do my insert using this code:

```
ArrayList<ContentProviderOperation> ops = new ArrayList<ContentProviderOperation>();
int rawContactInsertIndex = ops.size();
ops.add(ContentProviderOperation.newInsert(RawContacts.CONTENT_URI)
    .withValue(RawContacts.ACCOUNT_TYPE, null)
    .withValue(RawContacts.ACCOUNT_NAME, null)
    .withValue(RawContacts.AGGREGATION_MODE, RawContacts.AGGREGATION_MODE_DISABLED)
    .build());
```

I appreciate any inputs, be it a workaround or from the API. Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

you can use the information returned from getContentResolver() (which you anyways have to call in order to add ops to the DB.
getContentResolver() needs to have a try,catch environment.

```
...
ContentProviderResult[] res = getContentResolver().applyBatch(ContactsContract.AUTHORITY, ops);
...
Uri myContactUri = res[0].uri;
int lastSlash = myContactUri.toString().lastIndexOf("/");
int length = myContactUri.toString().length();
int contactID = Integer.parseInt((String) myContactUri.toString().subSequence(lastSlash+1, length));
```

Comment: Nice! Straight to the point with no hassle. Thanks for the help. =D